# Multithreading in C# giving error with Invoke method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm facing a bit of problem, it's giving error "Cross-thread operation not valid" even though I'm using Invoke method.

Here's the code snipit.

Method to update log box

```
private void updateStatus(String msg)
    {
        if (logBox.InvokeRequired)
            logBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                logBox.SelectionStart = logBox.Text.Length;
                logBox.Text += "\n";
                logBox.Text += msg;
            });
        else
            logBox.SelectionStart = logBox.Text.Length;
            logBox.Text += "\n";
            logBox.Text += msg;
    }
```

And this Run method is being run by a thread.

```
private void Run()
    {
        int port;
        try
        {
            port = Int32.Parse(broadcastPortTextBox.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        updateStatus("Starting server at port: " + port.ToString());
        server = new HTTPServer.HTTPServer(port);
        server.Start();
    } //function
```

It runs fine for the first time but when I click stop, it gives an exception.

```
private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateStatus("Stoping server");
        th.Abort();
        updateStatus("Server stoped!");
    }
```

Comment: There are many, many, MANY answers on questions about cross-threading invocation issues.

Comment: Your code seems fine,  You should debug it and see what line exactly it fails on, maybe it's occurring somewhere else.

Comment: @xtnd8 that's true. but he did check access and propagated the action back to the owning thread and he still gets the exception and that's the question here.

Comment: @eranotzap The code is not fine.  The `Run()` method which is _"run by a thread"_ is accessing `broadcastPortTextBox.Text` as well as potentially showing a dialog via `MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show()`

Comment: @all exception is being shown in updateStatus() method.

Comment: but he isn't updating it. he is just reading from it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using the direct cast for the invoke. There's no need to check whether the invoke is required or not. If you invoke something it should always happen (in your context). Just remove the **updateStatus(*String* msg)** method so and try  to cast your update like this:

```
void Run() {   
    // stuff     
    broadcastPortTextBox.Invoke(() => {
        port = Int32.Parse(broadcastPortTextBox.Text);
    });        
    // stuff..
    logBox.Invoke(() => {
        logBox.SelectionStart = logBox.Text.Length;
        logBox.Text += string.Format("{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, "Your message text..");
    });
    // stuff..
}
```

Note: If you manipulate any non thread owned element use the invoke method. Otherwise you'll end up with exceptions (see '***broadcastPortTextBox***');

Edit: Accidently saved before I was done.